# Connection refused to localhost:5432 through Docker Compose after already specifying the name of the service instead of localhost

Tags: spring, docker, docker-compose

I have a few microservices running under Docker. They are Zuul, Eureka, and a configuration server. These are working but when I start my `authorization-service`, it says I cannot connect to PostgreSQL.

```
version: '3'
services:
  eureka-discovery:
    ...
  zuul-gateway:
    ...
  config:
    ...
  postgres:
    image: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: root
      POSTGRES_DB: spring_microservices
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
  authorization-service:
    image: authorization-service:0.0.1
    environment:
      - eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://eureka-discovery:8761/eureka
      - spring.cloud.config.uri=http://zuul-gateway:8765/config-service
      - spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/spring_microservices
    depends_on:
      - eureka-discovery
      - zuul-gateway
      - config
      - postgres
    ports:
      - 1001:1001
```

What's confusing is that I am specifying `postgres` instead of localhost to make the connection, but the error continues to say "localhost". You see I override other properties the same way I do with `spring.datasource.url` and they work but this one.

> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.

I attempted a few variations I could find around, such as using a different service name, using `SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL`, using the connection string as `postgresql://[user]:[pass]@[service]/[database]`, I tried moving this line to the `config-service` instead since the database connection is indeed in the Spring Cloud Config Server microservice, but all to no avail. What's missing? It seems to be correct comparing to all the solutions I found.

Comment: can you show `application.yml` file ?

Comment: If you are trying to connect to localhost from inside the container , you need to use `host.docker.internal`. Read more here
https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/networking/#known-limitations-use-cases-and-workarounds

Comment: @NullPointerException, I don't think it is. It is an external container connecting to the database's, just like config and eureka.

Answer (score 0):

I made Spring Config Server see my repository for the configurations. Thinking better, if it's reading from the repository it's evident that changing it on the fly locally won't work, so I updated the connection string of the configuration file for `authorization-service` then pushed, and it worked. I wonder if this is a good practice or better to make Config Server see local files and change it on the fly?

Answer (score -1):

Hi i hope you are okay !

above your authorization-service add a link like this:

```
links: 
  - "postgres"
```

Greetings

Comment: Hi, the thing is I am not putting "localhost". As you may see in the `docker-compose-yml` file, I put the name of the service and I also tried the name of the container instead of localhost, but the error continues to say "localhost:5432".

Comment: Try to put a links of your postgresql

Comment: I don't know what you mean.

Comment: above your authorization-service add a link like this: 

  links:
    - "postgres"